# How can I get a script file to return to its initial prompt after a command is entered? (with loop)?

Tags: bash, shell-script

For example, I have the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Please enter function: \c"

read ANS

case $ANS in

author)

   echo "John"
;;
```

How can I get the script to return to the initial prompt (Please enter function), after it responds with my name?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308707 (I mean, literally identical question)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like

```
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    printf 'Say something: ' >&2
    read -r something

    case $something in
        quit) break ;;
        info) echo 'There is no info' ;;
        *) echo 'Invalid input' >&2
    esac
done

echo 'Bye!'
```

This is a typical read-action type of loop.  It's infinite, but the user can exit it by typing `quit`. After each action, the user is prompted for another input.

Alternatively, using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -p 'Say something: ' -r something; do
    case $something in
        quit) break ;;
        info) echo 'There is no info' ;;
        *) echo 'Invalid input' >&2
    esac
done

echo 'Bye!'
```

This would allow the user to press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> at the prompt to exit the loop, *or* enter `quit`.

A third way, with `bash`,

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Select something: '
while true; do
    select something in 'info' 'quit'; do
        case $something in
            quit) break 2;;
            info) echo 'There is no info'
                  break ;;
            *) echo 'Invalid input' >&2
        esac

        echo 'Press Enter to redisplay menu' >&2
    done
done

echo 'Bye!'
```

In this variation, the user is presented with a sort of menu to select things from.  After each action, the menu is re-displayed.  The user quits by selecting the `quit` choice.  The prompt text that `select` is using is taken from the `PS3` shell variable.

The `break 2` is needed to exit the `while` loop (instead of just `break`) since the `select` statement in itself is a loop.  The string `Press Enter to redisplay menu` will be displayed only when the user inputs an invalid choice (the way it's written here).

Any `break` inside the `select` statement would cause the the program to exit back out into the outer `while` loop, which would then immediately execute the `select` again (redisplaying the menu).  This is what happens if the user selects the `info` choice from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
    read -rp 'Please enter function: '
    case $REPLY in
        author)
            echo "John"
        ;; 
    esac
done
```

This will run until the user enters a break sequence which I don't recommend.  At the very least I would ensure there is an option to exit:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
    read -rp 'Please enter function: '
    case $REPLY in
        author)
            echo "John"
        ;; 
        exit)
            break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

---

Another option (if bash is available) would be a select menu:

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Select a function: '
select FUNC in author publisher release_date exit; do
    case $FUNC in
        author)
            echo 'John'
        ;;
        publisher)
            echo 'Penguin'
        ;;
        release_date)
            echo '1996'
        ;;
        exit)
            break 2
        ;;
        *)
            echo 'ERROR! Unknown selection' >&2
        ;;
    esac
done
```